# Help in Understanding the Formula for The Lattice Point Counting in Triangles with Rational Coordinates

Tags: combinatorics, integer-lattices

Yesterday I have found [this paper](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdomino.research.ibm.com%2Flibrary%2Fcyberdig.nsf%2F1e4115aea78b6e7c85256b360066f0d4%2F998d6b527637a012852572730025e777%3FOpenDocument%26Highlight%3D0%2Ca&ei=tXAhVKaaHsaKuASl3IJ4&usg=AFQjCNH2NIEFOK58OioaCezXaGnchtLLKQ&bvm=bv.75775273,d.c2E) while searching Google. However, since the author of this paper gave no examples of implementing the following formula, I don't understand how to implement it in practical cases. The relevant part of the paper is quoted below,

> ### Algorithm for Triangle
>
> ...
>
> **Definition 2**
>
> Let $a$ , $b$ and $c$ be positive integers. We define the right-angled triangle $T(a,b,c)$ as follows:
>   $$T(a,b,c)=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid ax+by \leq c,x>0,y>0\}$$
>
> **Definition 3**
>
> Let $a$ , $b$ and $c$ be positive integers. We define $N(a,b,c)$ as the number of lattice points in the triangle $T(a,b,c)$.
>
> ...
>
> **Lemma 5**
>
> Let $a$ , $b$ and $c$ be positive integers with $a>b$. Let $m=\left \lfloor \dfrac{c}{a} \right \rfloor$, $h=\dfrac{(c-am)}{b}$ and $c'=c-b \left (km+\left \lfloor h \right \rfloor \right)$. Then the following equation holds, $$N(a,b,c)=N(a-bk,b,c)+\dfrac{km(m-1)}{2}+m\left \lfloor h \right \rfloor$$

Can anyone give example(s) of the implementation of the above formula as represented in lemma 5? It will be very much helpful for me. Also, I don't understand why there is the requirement of $a$, $b$ and $c$ being positive integers. What problem would arise if we just assume that $a$, $b$ and $c$ are non-negative with at most one of them being $0$?

Comment: Could you include here the formula or statement in question?

Comment: And can you re-tag to indicate the area of mathematics we're talking about? and edit in a more informative title?